# Tumblr and Youtube: iframe error

Tags: iframe, youtube, tumblr, vimeo

I was unable to find any documentation or similar incidents regarding this
consistent error when inserting videos from YouTube (or Vimeo) in a Tumblr blog:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://foo.tumblr.com/
from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/iG4BFxgZxMU?
wmode=transparent&autohide=1&egm=0&hd=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1
&rel=0&showinfo=0&showsearch=0. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

(tested in Safari & Chrome with different videos, tumblr themes etc.)

Open your console; even this Pixelunion theme shows an error with a Vimeo video:
[Pixelunion theme](http://maximalist-theme.pixelunion.net/page/2)

Comment: To my knowledge, it's a warning not an error and I've always seen it in the console when loading Tumblr pages. I know it's likely yelling because they're cross-domain frame manipulations, but if you're asking how to make it go away? I have no idea.

Comment: It just strikes me as odd — at first I thought it was a problem in my script, a problem with my browser addons and before suspecting Tumblr.